# Laplace transform of a second order ODE

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform

This is my first time doing Laplace transform of derivatives and I'm not sure if my transform is correct.

The given expression is
$$y^{''}+3y^{'} +2y=t$$ 
and the given values are
$$y(0)=0, \space y^{'}(0)=2$$
What I got was
$$S^2Y-0-2+3SY-3(0)+2Y=\frac{1}{s^2}$$
Then solving for $Y$
$$Y=\frac{1}{(S^2)(S^2+3S)}$$
Is my work correct?

Comment: No, you should get $$Y(s) = \dfrac{2s^2+1}{s^2(s^2+3s+2)}$$

Comment: @Moo Could you show me what I got wrong?

Comment: Look at how you grouped $Y$ on the LHS, see it? Then, what do you get for $1/s^2 + 2$ when you combine them?

Comment: @Moo Ah yes I see now, thank you

Comment: Stupid algebra gets me every time too, so be careful because all the heavy lifting was already correct!